# Notice: Undefined variable: startdate

Tags: opencart

I am using open cart v 1.5.6.4. I am getting following error after using magic zoom module.

> Notice: Undefined variable: startdate in
>   C:\Users\kailash.SYSTEM1\workspace\designhut2\vqmod\vqcache\vq2-catalog_view_theme_METROPOLITEN_template_product_product.tpl
>   on line 28

Comment: Could you please post here only the part of the XML file (magic zoom extension) that is modifying your `catalog/view/theme/METROPOLITEN/template/product/product.tpl` and `catalog/controller/product/product.php` files? It looks like the template is using `$startdate` variable that wasn't initialized/set in the controller.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have two possibilities :

- Go in the source and initialize the undefined variable (like :
  `$startdate = '';`)
- Update your .htaccess to remove the display of the notices (or display_error off)

Comment: Any of the possibilities listed in your answer will solve the problem - the first option will solve the notice while probably something different won't work; the second one cannot be even recommended nor advised by a programmer - hiding consequences is never a solution to a problem.

Comment: Yeah you should use the firsrt answer. But in case of use third party code, you don't have to edit them because you break the update process. So it's why I've proposed the second solution. Based on my experience, you can't always correct bad code ;)   Please accept the answer if it solved your prob